# "Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, realm

I'm trying to use Realm in my app. I'm saving the data and all is good, but when I want to finally read it and send it to Firebase I'm getting an error.

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(sender: BouncingButton) {
    if !monday.isEmpty() && !tuesday.isEmpty() && !wednesday.isEmpty() && !thursday.isEmpty() && !friday.isEmpty() && !saturday.isEmpty() && !sunday.isEmpty() {
        Constants.ActivityIndicator.startActivity()

        self.days.setObject(["open":monday.open,"close":monday.close], forKey: "Monday")
        self.days.setObject(["open":tuesday.open,"close":tuesday.close], forKey: "Tuesday")
        self.days.setObject(["open":wednesday.open,"close":wednesday.close], forKey: "Wednesday")
        self.days.setObject(["open":thursday.open,"close":thursday.close], forKey: "Thursday")
        self.days.setObject(["open":friday.open,"close":friday.close], forKey: "Friday")
        self.days.setObject(["open":saturday.open,"close":saturday.close], forKey: "Saturday")
        self.days.setObject(["open":sunday.open,"close":sunday.close], forKey: "Sunday")

        let email = Constants.clubRegisterForm.email
        let password = Constants.clubRegisterForm.password
        let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)

        Constants.FirebaseAPI.Auth?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                Constants.ActivityIndicator.stopActivity()
                Constants.Alerts.checkErrors(error!)
            } else {
                let changeRequest = user?.profileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest?.photoURL = NSURL(string: "\(Constants.FirebaseAPI.CLUB_PICS)/\(self.uniqueCode)")
                changeRequest?.commitChangesWithCompletion({ (error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        Constants.ActivityIndicator.stopActivity()
                        Constants.Alerts.checkErrors(error!)
                    } else {
                        Constants.FirebaseAPI.Auth?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                Constants.ActivityIndicator.stopActivity()
                                Constants.Alerts.checkErrors(error!)
                            } else {
                                do {
                                    let realm = try Realm()
                                    try realm.write {
                                        let userDataFromRealm = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(ClubRegisterForm.self, key: 1)!
                                        let userData: [String:AnyObject] = ["clubName":userDataFromRealm["name"]!,"email":userDataFromRealm["email"]!,"address":userDataFromRealm["address"]!,"price":userDataFromRealm["price"]!,"phoneNumber":userDataFromRealm["phoneNumber"]!,"numberOfCourts":userDataFromRealm["numberOfCourts"]!,"bankAccount":userDataFromRealm["bankAccount"]!,"accountHolder":userDataFromRealm["accountHolder"]!,"branchNumber":userDataFromRealm["branchNumber"]!]

                                        Constants.FirebaseAPI.REF_USERS_CLUBS.child("\(self.uniqueCode)").setValue(userData, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in
                                            if error != nil {
                                                Constants.ActivityIndicator.stopActivity()
                                                Constants.Alerts.checkErrors(error!)
                                            } else {

                                                Constants.FirebaseAPI.REF_USERS_CLUBS.child("\(self.uniqueCode!)").updateChildValues(["OpenHours":self.days,"services":self.clubServices])
                                                Constants.ActivityIndicator.stopActivity()
                                                realm.delete(Constants.clubRegisterForm)
                                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.Segues.registered, sender: nil)

                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                } catch {
                                    Constants.Alerts.errorOccured()
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } else {
        Constants.Alerts.emptyFields()

    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can
>   only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction
>   - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

It says that I'm doing something wrong inside this function, but I'm not adding, creating or removing anything from Realm, only reading.

## Solution

I made a stupid mistake and i tried to do realm.remove outside the write, and i forgot about it

Comment: did you tried to make this `try! realm.write` ??? Its just a silly question because i do that for my project and as i can see you dont try to do it as the docs said.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios im doing it inside the do

Comment: replace `try realm.write {`  to `try! realm.write {`

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios im still getting the same error

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios never mind......
I made a stupid mistake, i forgot that i put realm.remove and it was outside of the write i guess

Comment: @orim553, if you've managed to solve your own problem, please post an answer outlining your solution to help future users.

Comment: Me to, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap code for creation, add, update or delete in this block

```
try! realm.write {
   // YOUR CODE HERE
   // like realm.add(yourData) or realm.delete(yourData)
}
```